# trying to print info from arraylist but I think im getting memory instead

Tags: java

So here is my code

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        ArrayList<Event> pairs = new ArrayList<Event>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
          int x = sc.nextInt();
          int y = sc.nextInt();
          pairs.add(new Event(x, y));
        }

        Collections.sort(pairs);

        for(int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++)
        {
          System.out.println(pairs.get(i));
        }
     }
```

I wanted to see that the .in file I gave it with this info

```
4
5 7
7 8
8 4
4 5
```

would be sorted correctly, but I wanted to print it out. When I went to try and print it though I got these values in return.

```
C:\Users\Kneer\Documents\CS2\SCroll>java Main < test.in
Main$Event@5a01ccaa
Main$Event@71c7db30
Main$Event@19bb089b
Main$Event@4563e9ab
```

am I traversing the Arraylist info incorrectly?

Comment: What is the `Event` class? You probably want to add a `.toString` method to it (or getters for `x` and `y`, and use those).  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're printing an object, which would print "ObjectName@HashCode" (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4))

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Event` class doesn't have any `toString()` implementation. If you add it, it should print whatever your `toString()` implementation prints.

If you look at `java.lang.Object` `toString()` implementation, it will be clear why it's printing these hex values -

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

So, the solution would be to override the `toString()` method and return your custom formatted object as String.

Answer (score 0):

Override the Event.toString() method or create an eventToString(Event evt) method that you can access.

```
public static String eventToString(Event evt) {
  return "Event["+evt.x +"," +evt.y+"]";
}
```

then you can use it in your current code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < pairs.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(eventToString(pairs.get(i)));
}
```